# Dual Axes with column drill down, Cannot column click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Dual Axes Highchart, wit a column drill down and a spline, there is problem for the column area below the level of spline, it does nt goes in drill down of column.

```js
 $(function() {
   Highcharts.setOptions({
     lang: {
       drillUpText: '<< Go To {series.name}'
     }
   });

   Highcharts
     .data({
       csv: document.getElementById('tsv').innerHTML,
       itemDelimiter: '\t',
       parsed: function(columns) {

         var brands = {},
           cpc = {},
           brandsData = [],
           cpcData = [],
           temp = {},
           versions = {},
           drilldownSeries = [],
           $container = $('#container'),
           chart = $('container').highcharts(),
           origChartWidth = 1500,
           origChartHeight = 600,
           chartWidth = origChartWidth,
           chartHeight = origChartHeight;

         // Parse percentage strings
         columns[1] = $
           .map(
             columns[1],
             function(value) {
               if (value.indexOf('%') === value.length - 1) {
                 value = parseFloat(value);

               }
               return value;
             });
         columns[3] = $
           .map(
             columns[3],
             function(value) {
               if (value.indexOf('*') === value.length - 1) {
                 value = parseFloat(value);

               }
               return value;
             });
         columns[4] = $
           .map(
             columns[4],
             function(value) {
               if (value.indexOf('*') === value.length - 1) {
                 value = parseFloat(value);

               }
               return value;
             });
         columns[5] = $
           .map(
             columns[5],
             function(value) {
               if (value.indexOf('*') === value.length - 1) {
                 value = value.split('*')[0];

               }
               return value;
             });
         columns[2] = $
           .map(
             columns[2],
             function(value) {
               if (value.indexOf('*') === value.length - 1) {
                 value = parseFloat(value);
               }
               return value;
             });
         $
           .each(
             columns[0],
             function(i, name) {
               var brand, version;

               if (i > 0) {

                 // Remove special edition notes
                 name = name.split('@@');

                 // Split into brand and version
                 version = name[1];

                 brand = name[0];

                 // Create the main data
                 if (!brands[brand]) {
                   temp[brand] = (columns[3][i]);
                   brands[brand] = temp[brand] + "@@" + columns[2][i] + "@@" + columns[5][i];

                 } else {
                   temp[brand] = (columns[3][i]);
                   brands[brand] = temp[brand] + "@@" + columns[2][i] + "@@" + columns[5][i];
                 }


                 // Create the version data
                 if (version !== null) {
                   if (!versions[brand]) {
                     versions[brand] = [];
                   }

                   if (version == 1) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Jan-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 2) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Feb-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 3) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Mar-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 4) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Apr-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 5) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'May-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 6) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Jun-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 7) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Jul-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 8) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Aug-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 9) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Sep-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 10) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Oct-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 11) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Nov-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else if (version == 12) {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'Dec-' + columns[4][i],
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   } else {
                     versions[brand]
                       .push([
                         'others',
                         columns[1][i]
                       ]);
                   }

                 }
               }

             });

         $.each(brands, function(name, y) {

           var data = y;
           var arr = data.split('@@');

           brandsData.push({
             name: name,
             p: name,
             dataLabels: {
               enabled: true,
               align: 'center',
               style: {
                 fontWeight: 'bold'
               }
             },
             y: parseInt(arr[0]),
             z: parseInt(arr[1]),
             a: arr[2],
             drilldown: versions[name] ? name : null
           });
         });
         $.each(brands, function(name, y) {

           var data = y;
           var arr = data.split('@@');

           cpcData.push({

             name: name,
             a: arr[2],
             p: name,
             y: parseInt(arr[1]),
             z: parseInt(arr[0]),

           });
         });

         $.each(versions, function(key, value) {

           drilldownSeries.push({
             name: key,
             id: key,
             data: value,


           });
         });

         // Create the chart
         $container
           .highcharts({
             chart: {
               type: 'column'
             },
             title: {
               text: 'Suggested Keywords'
             },
             subtitle: {
               text: 'Click the columns to view Monthly Searches. Source: Google Adwords.'
             },
             xAxis: {
               type: 'category'
             },
             yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
               labels: {
                 format: '{value}  Rs',
                 style: {
                   color: 'GREEN'
                 }
               },
               title: {
                 text: 'CPC',
                 style: {
                   color: 'GREEN'
                 }
               }
             }, { // Secondary yAxis
               type: 'logarithmic',
               minorTickInterval: 0.01,
               title: {
                 text: 'Search Volume',
                 style: {
                   color: '#00557F'
                 }
               },
               labels: {
                 format: '{value}',
                 style: {
                   color: '#00557F'
                 }
               },
               opposite: false
             }],

             plotOptions: {
               series: {
                 borderWidth: 0,
                 dataLabels: {
                   enabled: true,
                   format: '{point.y:.0f}',
                   color: '{series.color}',
                   rotation: -45,
                   y: -10
                 }
               }
             }

             ,

             tooltip: {
               shared: true,
               headerFormat: '',
               pointFormat: '<span style="color:Red;font-size:15px">{point.name}</span>: {series.name}:-<b style="font-size:15px;color:{point.color}">{point.y:.0f} <div style="color:black">{point.a}</div></b><br/>',


             },
             series: [{
               name: 'CPC',

               colorByPoint: false,
               color: 'GREEN',
               type: 'spline',
               marker: {
                 symbol: 'circle',
                 color: 'RED'
               },
               tooltip: {
                 valueSuffix: ''
               },
               data: cpcData
             }, {
               name: 'Search Volume',
               yAxis: 1,
               colorByPoint: false,
               color: '#00557F',

               tooltip: {
                 valueSuffix: 'Rs'
               },

               data: brandsData
             }],
             drilldown: {
               drillUpButton: {
                 relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                 position: {
                   align: 'left',
                   x: 30

                 }
               },
               series: drilldownSeries

             }
           });

         chart = $container.highcharts();
         $('<button>+</button>').insertBefore($container).click(function() {
           chartWidth *= 1.1;
           chartHeight *= 1.1;
           chart.setSize(chartWidth, chartHeight);
         });
         $('<button>-</button>').insertBefore($container).click(function() {
           chartWidth *= 0.9;
           chartHeight *= 0.9;
           chart.setSize(chartWidth, chartHeight);
         });
         $('<button>Default</button>').insertBefore($container).click(function() {
           chartWidth = origChartWidth;
           chartHeight = origChartHeight;
           chart.setSize(origChartWidth, origChartHeight);
         });
       }
     });



 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<!-- Data from www.netmarketshare.com. Select Browsers => Desktop share by version. Download as tsv. -->
<pre id="tsv" style="display:none">Browser Version Total Market Share month search volume year competition
samsung note 4@@2.0 90500% 9.6* 74000* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@1.0 110000% 9.6* 74000* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@12.0 135000% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@11.0 165000% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@10.0 165000% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@9.0 135000% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@8.0 49500% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@7.0 22200% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@6.0 14800% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@5.0 9900% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@4.0 8100% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4@@3.0 5400% 9.6* 74000* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@2.0 8100% 8.7* 9900* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@1.0 12100% 8.7* 9900* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@12.0 14800% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@11.0 18100% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@10.0 27100% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@9.0 27100% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@8.0 5400% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@7.0 2400% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@6.0 1900% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@5.0 1300% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@4.0 1000% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price@@3.0 720% 8.7* 9900* 2014* HIGH*
price of samsung note 4@@2.0 880% 14.9* 720* 2015* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@1.0 1000% 14.9* 720* 2015* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@12.0 1300% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@11.0 1900% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@10.0 1600% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@9.0 1000% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@8.0 170% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@7.0 90% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@6.0 70% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@5.0 40% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@4.0 40% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4@@3.0 40% 14.9* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 specification@@2.0 2400% 10.0* 2400* 2015* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@1.0 2900% 10.0* 2400* 2015* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@12.0 3600% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@11.0 4400% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@10.0 5400% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@9.0 5400% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@8.0 1600% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@7.0 1000% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@6.0 2400% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@5.0 1600% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@4.0 720% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 specification@@3.0 480% 10.0* 2400* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 india@@2.0 260% 5.3* 590* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@1.0 320% 5.3* 590* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@12.0 590% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@11.0 880% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@10.0 3600% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@9.0 1600% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@8.0 90% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@7.0 0% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@6.0 0% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@5.0 0% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@4.0 0% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 india@@3.0 0% 5.3* 590* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 price in india@@2.0 22200% 9.5* 18100* 2015* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@1.0 27100% 9.5* 18100* 2015* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@12.0 33100% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@11.0 33100% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@10.0 40500% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@9.0 33100% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@8.0 9900% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@7.0 4400% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@6.0 1900% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@5.0 1000% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@4.0 1000% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 price in india@@3.0 1300% 9.5* 18100* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@2.0 390% 14.4* 390* 2015* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@1.0 590% 14.4* 390* 2015* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@12.0 590% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@11.0 720% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@10.0 880% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@9.0 1000% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@8.0 320% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@7.0 170% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@6.0 110% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@5.0 70% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@4.0 70% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 mobile@@3.0 70% 14.4* 390* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@2.0 590% 14.2* 720* 2015* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@1.0 880% 14.2* 720* 2015* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@12.0 1600% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@11.0 1600% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@10.0 1900% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@9.0 1600% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@8.0 170% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@7.0 70% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@6.0 70% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@5.0 40% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@4.0 30% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
price of samsung note 4 in india@@3.0 0% 14.2* 720* 2014* MEDIUM*
samsung note 4 in india@@2.0 90% 8.7* 320* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@1.0 140% 8.7* 320* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@12.0 210% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@11.0 260% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@10.0 1600% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@9.0 1000% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@8.0 140% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@7.0 50% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@6.0 50% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@5.0 20% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@4.0 20% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 in india@@3.0 10% 8.7* 320* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@2.0 260% 47.1* 390* 2015* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@1.0 320% 47.1* 390* 2015* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@12.0 390% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@11.0 480% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@10.0 720% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@9.0 1000% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@8.0 720% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@7.0 320% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@6.0 210% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@5.0 70% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@4.0 50% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 gsmarena@@3.0 20% 47.1* 390* 2014* LOW*
samsung note 4 with price@@2.0 50% 5.0* 40* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@1.0 70% 5.0* 40* 2015* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@12.0 110% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@11.0 90% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@10.0 70% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@9.0 50% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@8.0 20% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@7.0 0% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@6.0 0% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@5.0 0% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@4.0 0% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*
samsung note 4 with price@@3.0 0% 5.0* 40* 2014* HIGH*

</pre>
```

click the part below the spline it wont work. help!!

Comment: Have you a reference drilldown in the spline series points?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: i hav no drill down in the spline. only in the column i have the drill down

Comment: But I understand that you have in both of them.

Comment: if i give the same drill down for both of thm, the drill down comes in green color which i do not want

Comment: Could you explain what is incorrect and how it should work?